# Convert Rows to Columns in SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I am getting 5 rows against an SQL query, data screenshot is given below:

[image]

I need to write SQL query which will convert these rows to 5 Cols. The result should be like this:

```
Col1 ---> Value of First Row

Col2 ---> Value of Second Row

Col3 ---> Value of Third Row

Col4 ---> Value of Fourth Row

Col5 ---> Value of Fifth Row
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [Here's an excellent resource to get you started.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: look up PIVOT and post where you get stuck

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP is looking for a resource on how to approach their problem.

Comment: i am not getting any answer box to answer this one rather than pivot we can use max and Case Conditions also

Comment: ;WITH CTE AS
(
Select LEFT(trm_desc,CHARINDEX(':',trm_desc)-1)As Col,
RIGHT(trm_desc,LEN(trm_desc)- CHARINDEX(':',trm_desc)-1)As Val,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY trm_desc) AS RN from @Table
)
Select 
MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1  THEN Val ELSE '' END )AS 'Select',
MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2  THEN Val ELSE '' END )AS 'Others' ,
MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3  THEN Val ELSE '' END )AS 'Payment' ,
MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 4  THEN Val ELSE '' END )AS 'Supply' ,
MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 5  THEN Val ELSE '' END )AS 'Taxes'  from CTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(trm_desc VARCHAR(300))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
('Supply: All goods supplied bla bla...'),
('Payment: to be made 10 April 2013'),
('Delivery: Today 07 March 2013'),
('Taxes: The price is bla bla...'),
('Others: other bla bla')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT LEFT(trm_desc, CHARINDEX(':', trm_desc)-1) AS Cols
      ,RIGHT(trm_desc, LEN(trm_desc)-CHARINDEX(':', trm_desc)-1) Value
FROM @Table) Q
PIVOT (MAX(Value)
       FOR Cols
       IN ([Supply],[Payment],[Delivery],[Taxes],[Others])
       )p
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═══════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║            Supply             ║         Payment          ║      Delivery       ║          Taxes          ║    Others     ║
╠═══════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ All goods supplied bla bla... ║ to be made 10 April 2013 ║ Today 07 March 2013 ║ The price is bla bla... ║ other bla bla ║
╚═══════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```